# IntelliJ: find file name with regex

Tags: regex, intellij-idea, ide, jetbrains-ide

IntelliJ have multiple ways to find things.
What I need is to find a file by name. It seems easy by pressing two times <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

The problem is, in the window that opens

[image]

that is seems to be no way to use regexp!

If a try to use a very simple one, to find files that not contains *solr*

[image]

Same for all kind of regex... does it exists a solution/workaround to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature is not yet supported, please vote for [IDEA-257632](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-257632) to be notified on any progress with it